# VBA Union Not Working As Desired

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, union

My code is not working. It breaks on the `uni.entirerow.delete` line, with error 1004. That indicates that it is building the array, but I must be referencing something wrong? I originally was just having it delete line=by=line, but it takes too long, and there are about 600k rows to go through.

The macro is supposed to reference if the value of Column B equals any of the values of `p` from `ws2`. If it does, add it to `uni` and then delete after the range is fully reviewed. Union is supposed to work much faster than deleting line by line.

Any ideas? Full code below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub TrimOut()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, p As Long
Dim uni As Range

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(2)

For i = 610197 To 591043 Step -1
    For p = 8 To 82
        If ws1.Range("B" & i).Value = ws2.Range("A" & p).Value Then
            'ws1.Rows(i).Delete old snippet, works fine
            If uni Is Nothing Then
                Set uni = ws1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow
            Else
                Set uni = Application.Union(uni, ws1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow)
            End If
        End If
    Next p
Next i

If Not uni Is Nothing Then
uni.EntireRow.Delete
End If

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

EDIT: Here is a 'working' code, though not optimal.

```
Option Explicit
Sub TrimOut()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, p As Long
Dim uni As Range
Dim count As Long

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(2)

count = 0

For i = 607257 To 1 Step -1
    For p = 8 To 82
        If ws1.Range("B" & i).Value = ws2.Range("A" & p).Value Then
            'ws1.Rows(i).Delete
            If uni Is Nothing Then
                Set uni = ws1.Rows(i)
            Else
                Set uni = Excel.Union(uni, ws1.Rows(i))
                count = count + 1
            End If
        End If

        If count > 1000 Then
            uni.Delete
            count = 0
        End If
    Next p
Next i

If Not uni Is Nothing Then
    uni.Delete
End If

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: have you check `uni.address` prior to `uni.entirerow.delete` to see whether there are anything bind to `uni`?

Comment: @Rosetta I added an `If Not uni Is Nothing Then` around the `uni.delete` to do what I believe you are suggesting, still Error 1004

Comment: can you give the full description of the error 1004?

Comment: i'm taking a wild guess here, try not to delete but instead do `uni.select`, then go back to the worksheet and delete the rows manually to see whether it is 'too complex for Excel to perform the operation'.

Comment: It selected them, but won't let me delete manually. Any idea why? Or how to fix? In the sample range I made, it has selected 3.6k rows.

Comment: any merged cells? array formula? protected sheet? that could prevent the deletion?

Comment: I think it's really just the volume. see my original post, I made an edit with a 'working' code. EDIT: A sort of working code. It still gives me the 1004 error and I need to restart it.

Comment: nice! i used this method to delete many rows before. i believe it could work as well for `count > 10000` to speed up the process

Comment: `uni` should be set to `Nothing` after `uni.Delete` and `count = 0` run.

Comment: @Mat'sMug You are correct. I edited my original post with what I 'think' is the most optimal solution to my problem.

Comment: ugh, that's messy. please keep the "question" for "question", and post answers as an "answer" - don't edit the question to include solutions, that's not how Q&A works

Answer (score 1):

I have just run your code and it seems that the slowness is not in the deletion, but in the nested loops. You iterate more than 1.4 million times ((610197-591043)*(82-8)) and each time you are probably changing a range. That is usually slow. Think of another way to do it, e.g. record the data in array or list and then try further.

To see yourself, write `Stop` on the line after `Next i` and see how quick it reaches it. Then the deletion is quite fast.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this then?

Comment: @MattCottrill - you can give it a try, by recording the rows in a list instead of making a union. Then turn off the animations and delete these rows. It could be that it is faster, but I am not sure.

Comment: Seems an autofilter and a selection of visible cells could do this without any loops.

Comment: @Mat'sMug you are correct that I could eliminate the values from the filter, but I need to comb the data with sumifs for the actual report I'm building, and I don't believe I can incorporate sumif(ONLY VISIBLE)?

Answer (score 0):

I've been running the below code successfully. I need to look at some metrics excluding 'top 5', 'top 10', etc for `p = 1 to 958` for some different reports. Thank you all for your help.

It appears the "real" issue was that excel doesn't want to delete groups of rows that aren't grouped, and throws an absolute hissy-fit.

It might be optimal to move the count loop before p, but whatever.

```
Option Explicit
Sub TrimOut()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, p As Long
Dim uni As Range
Dim count As Long
Dim lrow As Long


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets(2)

lrow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lrow To 1 Step -1
    For p = 1 To 82
        If Not uni Is Nothing Then
            If count > i + 1 Then
                uni.Delete
                Set uni = Nothing
            End If
        End If

        If ws1.Range("B" & i).Value = ws2.Range("A" & p).Value Then
            If uni Is Nothing Then
                Set uni = ws1.Rows(i)
            Else
                Set uni = Excel.Union(uni, ws1.Rows(i))
            End If
            count = i
        End If
    Next p
Next i

If Not uni Is Nothing Then
    uni.Delete
End If

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```